# How can I connect intelliJ with a Jira ticket?

Tags: intellij-idea, jira, ticket-system

is it possible to link a ticket created in jira with our software so that this ticket is displayed in our software?

And my second question would be, is it possible to update the frameworks and plugins in this software automatically? So if one gets an update, it should be automatically updated in the software.

sorry for my english

Comment: Does https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-tasks-and-context.html help? App dependencies are usually managed via the build system (Gradle/Maven). You can also [share the project files via the version control](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839).

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks, I'll try that.